# Sublime Text auto complete custom functions php

Tags: php, autocomplete, sublime-text-3

I can't bring ST to autocomplete functions that I have defined in other scripts. Once I use it in the script, it recognizes and suggests it. Otherwise it won't, I have to jump back and forth to copy paste my functions.

How can I get it to autocomplete these functions?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You need to provide examples, [MPV](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is possible, otherwise it will be impossible to tell what might be wrong

Comment: in functions.php i create a function called thisFunction().

In index.php I want to use that function, and when I start typing thisFunction, ST wont autocomplete. He wont recognize that I created this function. This means I have to type it or go to functions.php and copy the name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Out of the box, Sublime Text has no support for this. Autocompletions are either generated from static resources (`*.sublime-completions` and `*.sublime-snippets`) or from matching strings in the current document.

If I'm not mistaken, the [PHPIntel](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/PHPIntel) package adds the functionality you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you! There is actually a "All Autocomplete" package that does it. I discovered it looking into PHPIntel. Thanks!